# Controlling Sony A7RII with USB (NOT over WIFI)

Tags: api, sdk, camera, sony

In a project I'm developing I need to control Sony A7RII camera over USB. I saw that the SDK only supports Wifi but I decided to write this question anyway.
Is there a way, official or not, to control the camera over USB?

Gilad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the only way you can control the camera right now is over WiFi. Here is a link to some answers of other common questions if it is helpful:

https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/faq/

Comment: Tnx for your answer Robert. Please inform Sony development team that because of this (no USB control option) I'm basing a project I'm in charge of (~300 cameras & lenses) on the Canon 5DRS and not the Sony A7RII. The Sony A7RII fits better for the project but the lack of USB control is a deal breaker.